# Copy folder from remote server to local system on windows

Tags: ubuntu, scp

I am using following command to copy folder from remote server to my local system and I am on windows:

```
scp -r user@example.com: /var/www/projects/files/styles/image_style_150_ppi/public/misc/ C:\Users\shhu\photos
```

I am getting following error:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/shhu: No such file or directory
error: unexpected filename: .
```

Screenshot of error is also attached, any idea what to do?
your help will be really appreciated[image]

Comment: I have no idea how windows' broken implementation interprets backslashes, but it would seem highly likely you need to "escape" those characters.

The src address is also broken with whitespace, or has a redundant colon.

Is /home/shhu on the remote node?

Comment: you can use sftp which is enabled by default. here you can get a free windows client : https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space between `user@example.com:` and `/var/www/...` seems to be wrong.
You tried to copy all files from the home directory of the user user@example.com, which seems not to be allowed.